# How can I append information from a webiste to a google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets-api

This is my first post ever!

I have a website with a contact form and I want the info that is filled out by the user  (Name, phone, and email) to end on a Google spreadsheet.

I tried to do it but every time one submits the info he has to log into their google account, which is less than ideal. This happens because I am using the oauth, I think there is a way to do it with an API KEY but I am struggling to find info on hoe to do it.

I am completely new to the Google Sheets API and would appreciate any help.

Comment: About `I tried to do it but every time one submits the info he has to log into their google account, which is less than ideal.`, can you provide your script for this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.